# Postgres: Query the server name, IP address and the name of the instances running on the server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Is it possible to query the name and the IP address of a Postgres server (where the Postgres DBMS is running) (not the hostname or host IP address).

Also, I was looking for a query to get the name of each instance running on the server.

[image: like here the instance test].

I could not find anything to get this information via any query.

I am working on a project for my degree, and I really appreciate any help.

Comment: A PostgreSQL server has no name. There is no database query to return data about a different instance on the same machine. Besides, there are too many questions in your question. Please focus.

Comment: OK , I did not know that you can only ask one question. thanks anyway

Comment: You should spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the IP address of the PostgreSQL server with

```
SELECT inet_server_addr();
```

Note that the result depends on the network interface you used to connect (the server may have several different IP addresses).

There is no query to that can give you information about other instances running on the same machine; each instance has no idea about any other instances.